# VSTS Build Error: Could not find Local.xml in build error after upgrading Solution to Latest SF version

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines

We were upgrading Service Fabric package version for our application from 5.4 to 5.7. with this change, Local.xml in publish profiles got changed to Local.1Node.xml and Local.5Node.xml and there is no Local.xml anymore.

I was able to build the solution and deploy my local cluster as SF SDK 5.7 is installed in my machine.

But when it comes to VSTS CI, Build is failing with the below error.

```
2017-09-05T09:03:10.7060823Z ##[error]DeploymentLibrary\ServiceFabric\ServiceFabricMsBuild\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.ApplicationPackage.targets(52,5): Error MSB4018: The "GetApplicationParametersFiles" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'd:\a\1\s\<SF Application Type>\PublishProfiles\Local.xml'.
File name: 'd:\a\1\s\<SF Application Type>\PublishProfiles\Local.xml'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.FileSystem.FileOpenRead(String path)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.BuildTasks.GetApplicationParametersFiles.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

My question at first was, why the build server (Hosted Agent) was looking for Local.xml where there is no reference to it in the proj files.

after some initial search, i could find that as per [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted#software), Hosted agent has SF version 5.4 installed. may be this could be the reason it was looking for Local.xml instead of Local.5Node.xml

Is my analysis correct or there could be any other issue? Or
How do we make it work with Hosted Agents instead of Custom agents with SF 5.7 installed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this while building Service Fabric 5.7 project on hosted agent. How do you upgrade the project? Could you reproduce this issue with a new project? Could you share the detail log and a sample project on the OneDrive?

Comment: Hope you updated your VSTS release definition to the correct publish profile?

Comment: Try with VS2017 hosted agent? Although sayimg that  I have a guest application which publishes fine using nor.al Hosted agent. I would not have thought it should be looking for local*.xml anyway, sounds like you have the wrong publish profile selected in the task!

Comment: @starain-MSFT I got a similar issue when I didn't commit Local.*.xml. My CI build failed with a similar message. How can you specify this at build time?

Comment: @Mardoxx Could you share a sample project on the OneDrive?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Repro is here: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/482#issuecomment-332478531

Comment: @starain-MSFT posted workaround there too